# DHT11 Humidity/Temp Sensor showing incorrect values

Tags: arduino-uno, sensors, temperature-sensor

So I am trying to use a humidity sensor with an LCD, but have run into this problem I have yet to fix. My problem is that when it is turned on, it returns the values `Humidity: 255%` and `Temp: 255C`. I know for sure that I am getting a signal from the sensor and that is working 100% (I have tested it without an LCD display). I have asked about this in the Adafruit Discord server and someone brought up the possibility of the data being clipped somewhere in the data collection/signal processing/printing chain. Still very confused about how I can fix this, I ask for help.

Here is some code:

```c
#include <dht11.h>
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>

LiquidCrystal lcd(12, 11, 5, 4, 3, 2);

dht11 DHT;

#define DHT11_PIN 7

void setup(){
  lcd.begin(16, 2);
}

void loop()
{
  int chk = DHT.read(DHT11_PIN);
  lcd.setCursor(0,0); 
  lcd.print("Temp: ");
  lcd.print(DHT.temperature);
  lcd.print((char)223);
  lcd.print("C");
  lcd.setCursor(0,1);
  lcd.print("Humidity: ");
  lcd.print(DHT.humidity);
  lcd.print("%");
  delay(1000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Obviously the DHT sensor has not acquired data to make sure do as follows:

```
void loop() {
  float h = dht.readHumidity();
  float t = dht.readTemperature();

  if (isnan(h) || isnan(t) ) {
   lcd.setCursor(0,0);
    lcd.println("DHT not ready!");
    return;
  }
 lcd.setCursor(0,0); 
  lcd.print("Temp: ");
  lcd.print(t);
  lcd.print((char)223);
  lcd.print("C");
  lcd.setCursor(0,1);
  lcd.print("Humidity: ");
  lcd.print(h);
  lcd.print("%");
  delay(1000);
}
```

Make sure you connected the DHT the right way and **initialized**

```
DTH11

    Pin1 --> 5v and 10k ohm resistor

    Pin2 --> Arduino Pin7 and 10k ohm resistor

    Pin3 --> no connection

    Pin4 --> Gnd
```

Initialize correctly

```
    DHT dht(DHT11_PIN, DHT11);
```

and in setup() you have to start like

```
 dht.begin();
```

Now test and report back

Comment: I checked and it is telling me it that it cant read from the sensor. I beginning to think that this might be a hardware malfunction. I tried the sensor without the LCD and it worked fine, but the addition of it gives me errors. Is there a reason for this?

Comment: See my edit above

Comment: As Codebreaker mentions, it looks like you are missing a call to ` dht.begin()` in your setup function (and you need to check for NAN values)

Comment: This is better because I have a visual feedback message. It just constantly says DHT not ready. It makes me think it might be a hardware issue (with the Arduino I think). I just want to rule out every other possible problem before I assume it is an Arduino hardware issue.

Comment: Have you initialized correctly See my edit DHT dht(DHT11_PIN, DHT11); AND dht.begin(); IN setup() AND check wether you use resistors see above its unlikely that the sensor is NOT working

Comment: So I tried to do the same thing, but this time I used an LCD with an I2C bus on it. It only takes two analog signal connections, 5v, and ground. I tried it with the DHT11 and it worked. I think it may be a something with connections because with the original LCD I had a lot of connections which could be interrupting the DHT11.